# Simple way to create redirect URI for foursquare API

Tags: ios, foursquare

I m creating an app using foursquare API and apparently I will be needing a redirect URI. Is there any simple way to create this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Register a URL scheme for your app in the info.plist (CFBundleURLSchemes).
For example, if you register JohnDoe, your redirect uri would be JohnDoe:// so register that as your redirect uri with foursquare which when redirected after you make an authorization call, will trigger the call in your app delegate with parameters attached such as the access_token or whatnot.

```
application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make an authorization with WebView, you can use `http://localhost/` as Redirect URI.

Sample Code:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSString *URLString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    if ([URLString rangeOfString:@"access_token="].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSString *accessToken = [[URLString componentsSeparatedByString:@"="] lastObject];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```